# value in column between commas delimited

Tags: sql

I have data in the table where all values in the column between  double commas

example: 'EGHU3158543'

when inquiry the data I need to delete the first comma and last comma, I used the following code :

```
SELECT  ['EQ_NBR']   
FROM [OldExpress].[dbo].[SERVICE_EVENTS]
WHERE Substring(['EQ_NBR'], 1, LEN(['EQ_NBR']) - 1) = 'EGHU3158543'
```

it gives me error as result  : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Are you meaning apostrophes/single quotes? And why are you using single quotes and square brackets? I think that's your error.

Comment: Your example data has no commas, so your question is not clear.

Comment: yes i mean single quotes , so the all vlaues in the table between  single quotes  , example  'valuex'   , wheich this cused problem in the query in where condation

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? That's invalid standard SQL to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solve now by using the following code  :

SELECT

EQ_NBR, LEFT (RIGHT (EQ_NBR, len (EQ_NBR)-1),len(EQ_NBR)-2)as RemovalOfFiratAndLastCharacter

FROM [OldExpress].[dbo].[EQUIPMENT_USES]

where EQ_NBR like ''''+'EGHU3158543'+''''